# passing View from setContentView to non Activity class

Tags: android, android-activity, view, setcontentview

I want to pass View from `sentContentView` from one of my **Non-Activity Class**.The Non-Activity Class contains the **AdMob methods** which I want to utilize for several activities across my Application and I don't want to repeat the code. so to utilize `findViewById` in Non-Activity class I have to pass the View from setContentView. How I may be able to get to pass the view from Activity class setContentView to non Activity class.

Comment: Pass `Context` variable to non Activity class.

Answer (score 0):

Try Getting getting view by

```
View view = this.findViewById(android.R.id.content);
```

Add pass it to non Activity class.